# Securing Selenium web driver interaction

Tags: security, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

We are using Selenium web driver and chrome. Selenium web driver interacts with chrome using HTTP protocol. Any sniffing tool can listen to the data sent to chrome.

How to secure the HTTP communication used between webdriver and chrome?

Answer (score 2):

I'd say being worried about regression automation being sniffed is an unrealistic worry, however, if you're adamant that your automated testing does indeed need to be secure then there's a page in the selenium documentation that goes through handling HTTPS to secure the connection [here.](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.jsp#handling-https-and-security-popups)

Comment: We are using selenium in a environment where there is sensitive data. Also the document talks about the enabling HTTPS at the browser, I am intrested in enabling HTTPS on the chrome webdriver port.